# Showing and hiding nested list toggle with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, nested, hide, show

I have some problems showing and hiding certain elements of a nested list. My HTML code is as follows:

```
<ul class="unstyled">
        <li onClick="foo();">INFO 1234 - Some Code Subject
        <ul>
            <li class="sem_hide">Semester 1
            <li class="sem_hide">Semester 2
            <li class="sem_hide">Semester 3
        </ul>
        <li onClick="foo();">INFO 4567 - Some DB Subject
        <ul>
            <li class="sem_hide">Semester 1
            <li class="sem_hide">Semester 2
            <li class="sem_hide">Semester 3
        </ul>
</ul>
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
<script>
        function foo()
        {
            if($('li .sem_hide').is(":visible"))
            {
                $('li .sem_hide').hide();
            }
            else 
            {
                $('li .sem_hide').show();
            }
        }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

And my CSS like this:

```
<style>
    body{
        width: 600px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background: #efefef;
    }

    li .sem_hide{
        display: none;
    }

</style>
```

I'm new to web development and am currently facing a problem which is that when I click on a subject, all the semesters for all the subjects are shown but what I want is the semesters for just the clicked subject to be shown. Is there a workaround to get what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jQuery before you use it, pass this in foo to point source object.

```
<script>
        function foo(obj)
        {
            if($('.sem_hide', obj).is(":visible"))
            {
                $('sem_hide', obj).hide();
            }
            else 
            {
                $('.sem_hide', obj).show();
            }
        }
</script>
<li onClick="foo(this);">
```

Comment: JazakAllah khayr for this! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="unstyled">
    <li class = 'subject'>INFO 1234 - Some Code Subject
    <ul class = "semList>
        <li>Semester 1</li>
        <li>Semester 2</li>
        <li>Semester 3</li>
    </ul>
    <li class = "subject">INFO 4567 - Some DB Subject
    <ul class ='semList'>
        <li>Semester 1</li>
        <li>Semester 2</li>
        <li>Semester 3</li>
    </ul>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".subject").click(function(){
            $(".semList").hide();
            $(this).next(".semList").show();
        });
</script>
```